# Azure resources Audit details?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, graph-explorer

Is it possible to validate or check who has created/deleted resources apart from the azure resources group Audit log or deployment group?

As per my understanding system will hold an audit log for not more than 3 months.

And what in case someone deletes a resources group.. how to track who has deleted etc.

Appreciate your input/guidance or the best approach to capture such details.

Comment: Activity Log is the place where you would see all these information. Provided answer by Peter details it better

Answer (score 1):

All activities, including de deletion of resource groups, are recorded in the [Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log). It logs also the caller (username of the user that initiated the operation):

[image]

> As per my understanding system will hold an audit log for not more than 3 months.

You can [setup a continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=portal) of [the Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log) to for example a storage account or a [Log Analytics Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-workspace-overview). The retention for a Log Analytics Workspace can be set to a maximum of 730 days.

If you route the logs to a storage account you can have unlimited storage retention.

Answer (score 0):

- *As far as I know and as per the [**document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log), we don't have any way other than **Azure** **Activity logs** to find out the information related to activities done.
- And as you already know we have **90days** of retention time but if you want to get **longer retention** time you can create **diagnostic setting** and route to different locations.

[image]

- Here is the [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=portal) which will help you in creating **diagnostic settings**. *

[image]

[image]

[image]